# Perl WWW::Mechanize Web Spider. How to find all links

Tags: perl, web-crawler, mechanize

I am currently attempting to create a Perl webspider using WWW::Mechanize.

What I am trying to do is create a webspider that will crawl the whole site of the URL (entered by the user) and extract all of the links from every page on the site.

**What I have so far:**

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $urlToSpider = $ARGV[0];
$mech->get($urlToSpider);

print "\nThe url that will be spidered is $urlToSpider\n";

print "\nThe links found on the url's starting page\n";

my @foundLinks = $mech->find_all_links();

foreach my $linkList(@foundLinks) {

    unless ($linkList->[0] =~ /^http?:\/\//i || $linkList->[0] =~ /^https?:\/\//i) {

        $linkList->[0] = "$urlToSpider" . $linkList->[0];
    }

    print "$linkList->[0]";
    print "\n";
}
```

**What it does:**

**1.** At present it will extract and list all links on the starting page

**2.** If the links found are in /contact-us or /help format it will add 'http://www.thestartingurl.com' to the front of it so it becomes 'http://www.thestartingurl.com/contact-us'.

**The problem:**

At the moment it also finds links to external sites which I do not want it to do, e.g if I want to spider 'http://www.tree.com' it will find links such as http://www.tree.com/find-us.
However it will also find links to other sites like http://www.hotwire.com.

How do I stop it finding these external urls?

After finding all the urls on the page I then also want to save this new list of internal-only links to a new array called @internalLinks but cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: I've not used it but it looks like you can pass `url_abs => $urlToSpider` into `find_all_links` to only get the internal ones.

Comment: Fetching every page from a web site is unlikely to please the site owner if you do it with `WWW::Mechanize`.  I suggest you look instead at [Gungho](https://metacpan.org/module/Gungho) which is written for this sort of thing and will honour `robots.txt`

Comment: I recommend using a perl spidering module from CPAN too. If you want to get a list of links, and maybe check they work, you might find this tool handy http://linkchecker.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
my @internalLinks = $mech->find_all_links(url_abs_regex => qr/^\Q$urlToSpider\E/);
```

If you don't want css links try:

```
my @internalLinks = $mech->find_all_links(url_abs_regex => qr/^\Q$urlToSpider\E/, tag => 'a');
```

Also, the regex you're using to add the domain to any relative links can be replaced with:

```
print $linkList->url_abs();
```